# Using multiple JS files- variable/function overlap.

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I am referencing multiple JS files within a single HTML file. I know that there should be no overlap of Variable and Function names in these JS files. However, is that limited to **only Global Variables or all variables**(even local variables within a function)?

Comment: Only variables _in the same scope_. The JS files will only be sharing the global scope, so that's what you need to be careful with.

Comment: As per tmslnz's answer, if you wrap your scripts in `(function () { 'use strict'; /* script */ })();` then you cannot leak anything to the global scope accidentally. Only explicitly set properties on the `window` object will be global

Comment: Good point @WilliamB but watch out with `strict` as things do get pretty _strict_ and confusing sometimes :)

Comment: Hi @jagpreetsingh Please remember to accept answers that resolve your query.

Comment: @tmslnz i find the strict mode errors to typically bring attention to mistakes that would otherwise be missed. "var" is not usually left off an assignment to intentionally make a variable global (as window.variable is much more clear), so having an error thrown is more useful. Same with attempted deletion of non-deletable properties `delete Object.prototype` etc.

Comment: @WilliamB I agree that the enforcements of _strict_ can be handy! Linters though have broader coverage of many more potentially problematic patterns. For someone learning like OP I wonder if `strict` would cause unnecessary confusion…

Answer (score 1):

```js
// These will go into global scope

nonKeywordedVarA = true; // just don't

var nonKeywordedVarC = true;

function leaky () {
  nonKeywordedVarB = true;
}

// These will stay where you put them

function nonLeakyA () {
  var functionScoped = true;
}

function nonLeakyB () {
  var functionScoped = false;
}

if (true) {
  let blockScoped = true;
}

if (true) {
  let blockScoped = false;
}


leaky();
nonLeakyA();
nonLeakyB();

// Here we log global scope
console.log(typeof nonKeywordedVarA)
console.log(typeof nonKeywordedVarB)
console.log(typeof nonKeywordedVarC)
console.log(typeof functionScoped)
console.log(typeof blockScoped)
```

It is limited only to variables in the same scope:

1. variables declared without `var`, `let`, `const` keywords (e.g. someVar = true). These go leak straight into global scope (eg `window` object)
2. variables declared outside any function scope (or block scope in case of `let`)

In short the answer to your question is don't worry about variables with the same name in *different* scopes.

Comment: My test environment is currently down due to maintenance. Will test this and respond as soon as possible. Thank you so much for your reply!